# Storing Pointer to Another Object in NSMutableArray and Changing it

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, pointers, nsmutablearray

I have an object called `GraphicPath` which stores a `CGMutablePath` and a `UIColor` value for the fill color. I then have an `NSMutableArray` called `graphic` which stores a series of these `GraphicPath` objects which ultimately comprise an image that is drawn in `drawRect` of another class.

I also have a little module that pops up that lets the user change the color to this graphic. So I have a separate `NSMutableArray` that keeps track of all the colors in said graphic that interfaces with this module. Let's call it `colors`. I'd like to make it so whenever I make a change to `colors`, the corresponding color value in the `GraphicPath` also changes (so I don't have to go inside the Array of `GraphicPaths` to find it to change it).

So obviously the `UIColor` property in each `GraphicPath` property needs to have a pointer to a color in `colors`. I'm just so confused about how to keep a `UIColor` object pointer in the array `colors`, and make it so whenever I change this value, the corresponding value in a `GraphicPath` also changes.

Comment: So you have `GraphicPath` objects which have a `UIColor` property, and a mutable array of `UIColor`s. And you want when objects are 'changed' in the mutable array, for them to also change in the `GraphicPath`? But `UIColor` is not mutable, so the objects aren't being changed. Maybe you mean that when objects are added to and removed from the color array, each `GraphicPath` should ensure its color is still in the array? I really am lost as to what specific change happens to your array of colors and how that change is to be propagated back to the path objects. Can you expand on that?

Comment: If the user makes a change to a certain color, say a change to the color of the hat in the graphic, the change will be updated in that colors array to the index which stores the hat color. Then when the graphic gets redrawn, all the GraphicPaths that store the hat color, will also be changed because they refer to the address of the hat color in the MutableArray.

Comment: I see, so when then user replaces the color at index 3 with a new one,  all the `GraphicPath`s that have a `color` property storing the replaced color at index 3 should automatically start referring to the replacement color at index 3? It seems like the solution might involve having the color paths not own the colors but rather refer to them by some key or name or, in this case, index; when it comes time to draw they retrieve the color at the appropriate key / name / index...

Comment: Is what I want to do not possible?

Comment: Well what exactly do you want to do? As I said, if the graphic stores its color not as a UIColor property but by an index into an array of colors, that seems to address the issue; it can just choose which color to draw by looking it up in the array. If what you need to do is bind a property's value (specifically, both the pointer's value and the state of the object ownership) to an index in an NSMutableArray, I don't know any way to do it without additional code (wrapping the array in an object that implements the appropriate key-value coding methods and emits associated notifications).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is said in the comments, you need to make your GraphicPath object's UIColor field point to the corresponding object in the colors array. So that way changing of the object in the colors array will lead to "change" of the UIColor field of your custom object.
For example, if you have:

```
UIColor *color1, color2, color3, etc;
NSMutableArray *colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:color1, color2, color3, nil];

NSMutableDictionary *graphicDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[graphicDictionary setObject:somePathObject forKey:@"path"]
[graphicDictionary setObject:[colors objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"color"];
GraphicPath *firstGraphicPathObject = [[GraphicPath alloc] initWithDitionary:graphicDictionary];
```

So next if you will change one of the color's objects, you will change the color# variables, and so you will change the value, returned by your objects field.
Something like that I guess.